# jQuery: Can I send and receive an $.ajax response while a longer $.ajax request is pending?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, insert

**Situation:**
I'm using an $.ajax() POST to send a request to a php script that inserts about 400,000-500,000 lines into a db.  This consistently takes about 3.5 - 4 minutes. (During this time, the request is PENDING).

**Problem:**
I need some way to show progress on the page. (such as a %).  I tried using an $.ajax() in a setInterval that checks every 5 seconds or so, but they seem to build up and all come through when the first (longer) $.ajax() is finished.

**Question:**
Isn't $.ajax() async by default?  Shouldn't this mean requests can be sent out in any order and at any time, and responses should be received in any order and at any time?? Does this even have anything to do with async? Is there a way to periodically send back 'semi-responses' from one request? Or can't I send and receive requests/responses while there is a pending request/response?  (see awesome drawing below)

Thanks in advance!!!

[multiple requests http://kshaneb.com/reqres.png](http://kshaneb.com/reqres.png)

Comment: +1 for the graph. :) Did you consider chunking your data, i.e. sending separate requets every 10k rows?

Comment: +1 for explanation. did u tried with async true..

Comment: I agree with Zsolt above, Consider chunking your data into several smaller request that can give you faster response, also you can calculate % basis of no of requests completed. Also uploading large data in single request, although async, will also result in slower performance.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy, I was considering that however, it's actually about 8 different tables that make up the 500,000+ lines.  Some tables have 3 rows and some have 300,000+.  I could still probably chunk it up but didn't really want to deal with deciding how much to chunk etc.  It looks like optimistiks answer might be it.

Answer (score 8):

Your long-running ajax-call probably opens a session on server, so all next requests are blocked due to a session file lock.

> **Problem:**
>   PHP writes its session data to a file by default. When a request is made to a PHP script that starts the session (session_start()), this session file is locked. What this means is that if your web page makes numerous requests to PHP scripts, for instance, for loading content via Ajax, each request could be locking the session and preventing the other requests from completing.
>   The other requests will hang on session_start() until the session file is unlocked. This is especially bad if one of your Ajax requests is relatively long-running.
>
> **Solution:**
>   The session file remains locked until the script completes or the session is manually closed. To prevent multiple PHP requests (that need $_SESSION data) from blocking, you can start the session and then close the session. This will unlock the session file and allow the remaining requests to continue running, even before the initial request has completed.

More info here:
http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/

Comment: [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here (not only the cause, but also the solution), and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you @optimistiks.  As suggested in that article, I'm using the session_write_close() before I'm running the time consuming part of my php script and... It's working! Well on localhost anyways.  I'm sure when I push it all to the server there will be new issues.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
$(function ()
    {
        var statusElement = $("#status");

        // this function will run each 1000 ms until stopped with clearInterval()
        var i = setInterval(function ()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                success: function (json)
                {
                    // progress from 1-100
                    statusElement.text(json.progress + "%");

                    // when the worker process is done (reached 100%), stop execution
                    if (json.progress == 100) clearInterval(i);
                },

                error: function ()
                {
                    // on error, stop execution
                    clearInterval(i);
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Your AJAX call contains no URL. Perhaps it should.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing an ajax post you can post to an iframe and have php generate incremental output and send it with the [flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) command.

```
 // send a hash mark for every 1000 inserts
 $a = 0;
 while ($rec = getDataForNextInsert()){
       $a++;
       // do insert
       if ($a%1000 == 0) { echo '#'; flush(); }
 }
```

It would also then be possible to poll the contents of the iframe to provide a pretty display for the end user.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will be useful for you

First of all, you need to disable output buffer in your PHP script

```
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
ob_implicit_flush(1);
```

Then you need to echo your progress from the PHP during the process, something like that:

```
for($i=0;$i < 20;$i++){
    echo ($i > 0 ? "#":"").($i/20*100);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Then, in javascript you need to listen for xhr readystate change event and when this happens, just parse the response text and show the progress as you want to.

listening for event:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, _, jqXHR ) {
                if ( options.onreadystatechange ) {
                    var xhrFactory = options.xhr;
                    options.xhr = function() {
                        var xhr = xhrFactory.apply( this, arguments );
                        function handler() {
                            options.onreadystatechange( xhr, jqXHR );
                        }
                        if ( xhr.addEventListener ) {
                            xhr.addEventListener( "readystatechange", handler, false );
                        } else {
                            setTimeout( function() {
                                var internal = xhr.onreadystatechange;
                                if ( internal ) {
                                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                        handler();
                                        internal.apply( this, arguments ); 
                                    };
                                }
                            }, 0 );
                        }
                        return xhr;
                    };
                }
            });
```

and sample of ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "test.php",
                    cache: false,
                    onreadystatechange: function( xhr ) {
                        res = xhr.responseText.split("#");
                        $("#id").html(res[res.length-1] + "% done<br/>");
                    }                   
                }).done(function( data ) {
                        $("#id").append("all done!</br>");
                    }); 
            });
```

tested with jQuery 1.5+

Comment: it helped me, thanks. do you know any issue about crossbrowser compatibility with these codes?